# Need help proving that $3\mid(14^{2n} - 1)$ for all n = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Tags: divisibility

I've been stuck on this mathematical proof for quite some time now.

So far I have tried using the division algorithm to prove the theorem by letting

$n = 3 \times q + r\ |\ q \epsilon N$

This gives me three different cases for values of n.

(i) $n = 3 \times q + 0$

(ii) $n = 3 \times q + 1$

(iii) $n = 3 \times q + 2$

Basically what I am thinking now is that if I can prove that all three of these cases are divisible by 3 then $(14^{2n}-1)$ must be divisible by all n = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

So I try to prove the theorem for case (i)

$14^{3\times q \times 2}-1 = 14^{6 \times q} - 1$

Now I'm stuck. What steps can I take to prove that this is divisible by 3?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: Since $14\equiv -1 \pmod{3}$, then $14^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$14\equiv-1\mod 3$ and $14^{\color{red}2n}\equiv\bigl( (-1)^2\bigr)^n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=0$ we have $14^{2n}-1=0$, and $13$ divides $0$. For $n\ge 1$
\begin{align*}
14^{2n}-1&=\left( 14^2\right)^n-1\\
&=(14^2-1)\left[(14^2)^{n-1}+(14^2)^{n-2}+\ldots+14^2+1\right]\\
&=(14-1)(14+1)\left[(14^2)^{n-1}+(14^2)^{n-2}+\ldots+14^2+1\right]\\
&=13(14+1)\left[(14^2)^{n-1}+(14^2)^{n-2}+\ldots+14^2+1\right]
\end{align*}
So $13$ divides $14^{2n}-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$14=2$ mod 3 implies $14^2=14^{2n}=1$ mod 3. We deduce that $14^{2n}-1=0$ mod 3.

Answer (score 0):

If a square $a^2$ is not a multpiple of $3$, then $a^2-1$ is.

Indeed, $a^2-1=(a+1)(a-1)$. Exactly one of the numbers $a-1$, $a$, $a+1$ is a multiple of $3$ and the result follows.